# I have made a script using selenium IDE, so how can I save it so that I can run the same script in future?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have made a script by using selenium IDE and it works fine but if I save it I am unable to use that script again. Please tell me how I can use my script again and again.

Comment: Hi Gaurav and welcome to SO. Are there any specific errors you are getting when trying to re-use your script? Post the actual steps you are undertaking to reproduce your behavior. This would help people greatly to be able solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

once try in this way....

Goto file click on save and save file with ".html" extention.